# Python Socket Programming - Client Port Number

Tags: python, sockets, server

I'm building a Server-Client network in Python and I've failed to find any resource that mentions how **the client's port number can be retrieved and send back to the client**.

Is there a way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be hard to find considering [socket.accept](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) returns it with every accepted connection. So does [socket.recvfrom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom). A typical IPv4 socket address looks like:

```
>>> socket.getaddrinfo('www.google.com','www')
[(2, 1, 6, '', ('64.233.163.99', 80)),
 (2, 1, 6, '', ('64.233.163.104', 80)),
 (2, 1, 6, '', ('64.233.163.147', 80)),
 (2, 1, 6, '', ('64.233.163.105', 80)),
 (2, 1, 6, '', ('64.233.163.103', 80)),
 (2, 1, 6, '', ('64.233.163.106', 80)),
 (10, 1, 6, '', ('2a00:1450:4010:c06::6a', 80, 0, 0))]
>>> _[0][4]
('64.233.163.99', 80)
```

That 80 is the port number.